# Best way to read properties file in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties, environment-variables

I'm using Spring and I need to use some properties file to retrieve information in several classes.
What is the best way avoiding xml code but only with annotation?
For example I tried with this code:

```
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class FleetFolderName {

    @Autowired
    private static Environment env;

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_FILESYSTEM_BASEPATH = "filesystem.basepath";

    public static String createFleetName(Fleet fleet){
        String path=env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_FILESYSTEM_BASEPATH) + fleet.getApplication() + " " +  
                fleet.getCubic() + " " + fleet.getPower() + " " + fleet.getTransmission() + " " + fleet.getEuroClass();
        return path;
```

but env variable is null so I receive exception.This is the same approach of my configuration class but there works fine

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "com.*" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ SpringMvcInitializer.class })
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.repository")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
```

**UPDATE** With @Imran code:

```
public class FleetFolderName {

    @Value("filesystem.basepath")
    private static String PROPERTY_NAME_FILESYSTEM_BASEPATH;

    public static String createFleetName(Fleet fleet){
        String path= PROPERTY_NAME_FILESYSTEM_BASEPATH + fleet.getApplication() + " " +  
                fleet.getCubic() + " " + fleet.getPower() + " " + fleet.getTransmission() + " " + fleet.getEuroClass();
        return path;
```

configuration class:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "com.*" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ SpringMvcInitializer.class })
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.repository")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";

    //Reead properties file so can access to its properties through @Value
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        List<Resource> resources = new LinkedList<Resource>();
        resources.add(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
        //resources.add(new ClassPathResource("config2.properties"));
        configurer.setLocations(resources.toArray(new Resource[0]));
        configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return configurer; 
    }
```

Project structure:

[image]

Comment: Anything wrong with `@Value`

Comment: it is the same of WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a bean of `PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer` class in you WebMvcConfigurerAdapter to load properties files.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    List<Resource> resources = new LinkedList<Resource>();
    resources.add(new ClassPathResource("config.properties"));
    resources.add(new ClassPathResource("config2.properties"));
    configurer.setLocations(resources.toArray(new Resource[0]));
    configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return configurer;

}
```

After that you can access all the propperties of config.properties file through annotation

```
@Value("${proprtyName}")
```

If you have few more properties files you can annotate your config class to include those properties files something as given below.

```
@PropertySource(value="config2.properties")
@Configuration
public class ConfigHandler{
}
```

Project structure:

[image]

Comment: and if i have several properties files how can I recognize the different files?

Comment: you can add it in same way or you can use @PropertySource annotation to include those properties files. see my updated answer

Comment: I have tried but PROPERTY_NAME_FILESYSTEM_BASEPATH is null

Comment: Try annotating FleetFolderName class with @Component or declare it as bean class in WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Comment: I tried with @Component and didn't work. I have tried also @Value("${filesystem.basepath}")

Comment: It should work man!!!. Is your FleetFolderName is getting scanned? Try once declaring it as a bean in WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Comment: Maybe the problem is static method... Yes without static all works

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SpringBoot, using annotation could be the best to access properties file.

```
@Value("${proprtyName}")
private String propertyvalue;
```